# Login system with MooTools (Ajax)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, mootools

I have this login form at my page. I have to query the MySQL database to see if the typed in user exist, if the password is correct, ect. I want to do this with AJAX (MooTools). I have my login-process.php file which looks like this:

```
    //Connect, prepare, execute and bind
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','db');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username=?");
$stmt->bind_param('s',//I need to get the typed in username from the index.php file);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($get_id, $get_username, $get_password);
$stmt->fetch();

if($stmt->num_rows!=0){
    //Check if the passwords match
    if($get_password==//I need the typed in password here){
        echo('Passwords match');    
    }
}
else{
        echo 'User dosn\'t exist';
}
```

Now, how can I get the values typed in the fields and use them in this file? Remember, I want to use AJAX (MooTools).

I hope you understand my question. It's kind of hard to explain in words :) Thanks!

Comment: There are reasons login isn't done with ajax. Security and complexity are only two of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know mootools, but I looked it up (Google is your friend with questions like this) and think the following will work.

```
// JavaScript (MooTools):
var myRequest = new Request([method:"POST", url:"login-process.php", onSuccess:  function(responseText){
    document.id('response').set('text', responseText);
}]);
myRequest.send("username="+username+"&password="+password);
```

`username` will have to be set to the username, say with `username = document.id('userNameField').value`, if there is a text-box with an id of `userNameField`.

The response would be put into a `div` with an id of `response`.

I'd be able to help more if I knew MooTools, if you need an example in regular JavaScript just ask.
If anyone could improve this by editing, please feel free!

Comment: Okay, thank you! But how can I then get access to those values in the login-process.php file?

Comment: `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']` will be set to the username and password.

Comment: So I can access them with $password and $username

Comment: Yes, but is better to get them with the `$_POST` array, I think it was for security reasons.  I forget where I read that.

Comment: Can you post a link to the page where you saw this?

Comment: [Request Documentation](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request) wasn't all that easy to understand, but looking at a few of the examples allowed me to combine MooTools requests with my knowledge of regular AJAX calls.

Comment: Your should think about hashing the password before sending it in plaintext through the internet...

Comment: Yes, I meant for this to be modified before use, and I only know regular JS, this was the first time I have looked at MooTools.